# Searching for images with tags

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database of about 700 pictures but I want to create a search bar so I can find them by tags.

How would I start doing this.

I believe you would add tags to mysql database...How do I do this, and how would I do multiple tags?

Comment: For multiple tags, look into a "many to many" table structure...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have an additional table `tags`, whose columns would be: `id` and `name`, which will hold all possible tags, and another table `image_tags` which would have an `image_id` and a `tag_id`.

```
|   tags   |
+---+------+
| 1 | cats |
| 2 | dogs |
| 3 | foo  |

|         image_tags        |
+---------------------------+
| 1 (cat image)         | 1 |
| 1                     | 3 |
| 2 (dog image)         | 2 |
| 3 (cat and dog image) | 1 |
| 3                     | 2 |
```

This way, the same image can have multiple tags, and the same tag can appear on multiple tables.

This is called a **many to many relationship**.

Answer (score 0):

This is classic "many to many" relation.

To create tag based system you should create 2 new tales in DB (assume "tags" and "tags_images" tables).

In "tags" table you gona have 2 fields: "id" and "tag".

In "tags_images" table you gona have 3 fields: "id", "tag_id" and "image_id".

So to add a tag to iamge simply add new record to "tags_images" table connecting tag (by 'tag_id') and image (bt "image_id").

Also you have to add a new tag to "tags" table in there is no such.

To get all the images with tag "dog" you should make simple sql JOIN query like:

```
SELECT `tags`.*, `images`.*
FROM `tags` t
INNER JOIN `tags_images` ti ON t.`id` = ti.`tag_id`
INNER JOIN `images` i ON i.`id` = ti.`image_id`
```